# Illegal characters in path when NuGet tries to remove old package from packages folder

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

Suddenly I'm getting an error when trying to update NuGet packages (or doing anything with NuGet packages). The error says it has something to do with the path but the path has not changed. Does anyone recognize this?

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 version 15.8.5

Below is a copy of the output from Package Manager. The update was triggered manually from the "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." dialog.

It looks like the new version of the package is successfully installed. The problem occurs when the old package is to be removed from the packages folder.

> Found package 'GenericParser 1.1.6' in 'C:\vsts\FLOTT\Main\packages'.
>
> Removed package 'GenericParser 1.1.5' from 'packages.config'
>
> Successfully uninstalled 'GenericParser 1.1.5' from Flott.App
>
> Package 'GenericParser.1.1.6' already exists in folder 'C:\vsts\FLOTT\Main\packages'
>
> Added package 'GenericParser.1.1.6' to 'packages.config'
>
> Successfully installed 'GenericParser 1.1.6' to Flott.App
>
> Removing package 'GenericParser 1.1.5' from folder 'C:\vsts\FLOTT\Main\packages'
>
> Illegal characters in path.
>
> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
>      at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
>      at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.GetFullPath(String path, Boolean checkForIllegalDollar)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Client.GetLocalWorkspace(String localPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)

Comment: I noticed that package manager places an empty file ending with .deleteme in the packages folder when a package update fails. If I delete this file and try to update the same package a couple of times it finally works. But this has to be done for each package, one by one and it takes a lot of time

Comment: Does this issue happen to your local? I see the error seems to come from TFS...

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT It must be local. The packages folder is not under source control.